# SQL - depending dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a time series table which looks like the following:

```
ID  Date        Value  
 1  2016-11-01    1.0 
 1  2016-11-03   1.76
...
```

i.e. just consecutive values for each of them. I also have a table like this:

```
ID  class  Date   
 1  c1     2016-11-01
 1  c2     2016-12-02
 1  c3     2017-02-03
...
```

i.e. a table that tells what class the ID belongs to. The date represents what date it starts to apply and then applies until the next row (date) in the table.

I need to join them together in some way to have a complete time series for the 'class' column as well:

```
ID  class  Date        Value 
 1  c1     2016-11-01  1.0 
...
 1  c2     2016-12-02  2.5  
...
 1  c3     2017-02-03  3.7
...
```

Does anyone have a good solution/hint on how to implement this?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? You have too many tags. Edit: Someone removed them just now in an edit. This comment as per original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41266206/1

Comment: Pick a DBMS, not all of them.

Comment: Something useful about [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Bad sample data. All ID have same values.

Comment: See https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/ on JOINS and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Hehe, lots of wrongdoings here. @Fred-ii- Thought of adding what RDBMS but decided not to since I can use them both (SQL Server and Oracle which I believe are the most common).

Comment: @user2069136 If you feel that both tags should be included, then you can add those in an edit, which would help others also. Oracle does have some differences between other RDBMS's and vice-versa, such as MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for Oracle. Adapt as needed. The top part is not part of the solution (see the COMMENT in the code); I use it just for testing. I added one more row in the first table to confirm that the query works correctly for dates beyond the last date in the second table. Also, in Oracle **date** is a reserved word, so it shouldn't be used as a column name. I changed it to **dt**.

```
with 
     your_first_table ( id, dt, value ) as (
       select 1, date '2016-11-01', 1.0  from dual union all
       select 1, date '2016-11-03', 1.76 from dual union all
       select 1, date '2017-04-11', 2.34 from dual
     ),
     your_second_table ( id, class, dt ) as (
       select 1, 'c1', date '2016-11-01' from dual union all
       select 1, 'c2', date '2016-12-02' from dual union all
       select 1, 'c3', date '2017-02-03' from dual
     )
-- end of test data; SQL query begins below this line
select t1.id, t2.class, t1.dt, t1.value
from   your_first_table t1
       left outer join
       ( select id, class, dt as from_dt, 
                lead(dt) over (partition by id order by dt) as to_dt
         from   your_second_table
       ) t2
       on       t1.id  = t2.id
          and   t1.dt >= t2.from_dt
          and ( t1.dt  < t2.to_dt   or   t2.to_dt is null)
;

  ID CLASS DT              VALUE
---- ----- ---------- ----------
   1 c1    2016-11-01          1
   1 c1    2016-11-03       1.76
   1 c3    2017-04-11       2.34

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: Nice!! Way to go @mathguy. Thanks.

Comment: *"Also, in Oracle date is a reserved word"* - Wouldn't using ticks `\`` around it work just as in using MySQL reserved words?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Close (different syntax). In Oracle you can escape identifiers (table names, column names etc.) by enclosing them in double-quotes. But that is a poor practice; if you use double-quotes then you must use them everywhere, and keep the same capitalization, etc. Much better to get in the habit of not using reserved words for table and column names in the first place (while it is good, too, to know the "workaround" if and when needed).

Comment: @mathguy Oh, I see thanks. TBH, I don't know much about Oracle syntax but that doesn't stop me from "Googling" haha! *Cheers*